How to randomly zoom video with a Batch script?
I deal with the processing and uniqueness of 9:16 videos.
I need to make the video take on a random zoom value to increase it in scale and crop it accordingly at the edges.
I need to make a random value from +1% to +10%. From the original 100%
The command I have, it only changes the zoom to +30%.
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%G in (*.mp4) do (
    set "video_file=%%G"

    set /a "random_int=!RANDOM! %% 401 + 100"
    set "trim_start=!random_int:~0,-2!.!random_int:~-2!"

    echo Processing "!video_file!" with trimming start by !trim_start! seconds

    set "output_file=!video_file:.mp4=_zoomed.mp4!"

    ffmpeg -i "!video_file!" -vf "crop=iw/1.3:ih/1.3" -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset medium -c:a copy "!output_file!"

    if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
        echo Error processing "!video_file!"
    ) else (
        echo Successfully processed "!video_file!"

        ren "!output_file!" "!video_file!"
    )
)

pause


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Since this involves ffmpeg, you may also get good answers on the VIdeo Production stack. https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ffmpeg

You don't seem to use the variables you created trim_start or random_int at any part of the ffmpeg command...
